# Dynamic Dropdown Bootstrap for each user

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a website where there are different users (administrator, normal user, student, secretary, etc.)
each user has a unique content to see.
I am trying to do is use the navbar boostrap and create a dropdown button to load the pages that each user can use.

eg

Secretary Module

navbar:

Home | Contact | Menu |

```
             - Secretary Things
             - Forms
             - Etc
```

Admin Module

navbar:

Home | Contact | Menu |

```
             - Things Admin
             - Add User
             - Delete Things
             - Etc
```

can be done this in asp.net c #? or jquery or javascript?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done with jQuery, or if you're using an MVC like ember.js you can use {{#if}} helpers. For js, just check an application state. (Although it would be better to just use an mvc like ember, if your users are too crafty, they can spawn the menu for themselves with simple js)

```
var studentMenu = "<button></button>MORE HTML";
var adminMenu = "<button></button>MORE HTML";

if(loginState === "admin") { //check a login state from a server or something. I would not store the loginState as a global variable.
    $(".navbar-menu").html(adminMenu);
} else if() { //more loginStates
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in C#, jquery, even in plain javascript.

In C# you can check the user type and only add the menu options available.

In jQuery or javascript you can add a user type to the request like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var UserType: '<%=UserType%>'
</script>
```

Through jquery/javascript you can manipulate the menu options like this.

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li class="opt-admin">Visible to Admin</li>
   <li class="opt-secretary">Visible to Secretary</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#menu li').hide();
   $('#menu .opt-' + UserType).show();
</script>
```

It's up to you on which method you want to use. There's a lot of ways to do it. Basically all 3 can do what you want.